# Is the set of numbers $x$ with $\frac{x}{\pi} = \frac{m}{n} $ dense in $[0, \pi]$?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-number-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, rational-numbers

Take a set $A = [0,\pi]$ and consider the set $B \subset A$ of all numbers $x \in A$ such that $\frac{x}{\pi} = \frac{m}{n}$ where $m,n \in \mathbb{Z}$. Then:

1. Is $B$ dense in $A$?
2. What is the measure of $B$?

Comment: Hint: $A = \pi(\mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1])$. The function $f(x) = \pi x$ is continuous and bijective.

Comment: Have you tried anything? (Also, do you know about cardinality?)

Comment: There is an immediate correspondence between your subset $B \subset A $ and the rational numbers in $[0,1]$.  The correspondence is fruitful for both the problems of density and measure.

Comment: Well the rationals are dense in reals, and the measure of rationals in a $A$ is zero, but I'm not sure where to go from there. I am not at all familiar with cardinality theory @NoahSchweber

Comment: Ah, so you are saying that $B$ is indeed dense in $A$ and its measure is $0$? On what facts is this correspondence based? @hardmath

Comment: Could you explain why $A = \pi (\mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1])$ ? When you take intersection of $\mathbb{Q}$ with $[0,1]$ you obtain all rationals in $[0,1]$ so how can you, by multiplying by $\pi$, obtain $A$? @DarkMalthorp

Comment: Well if $x \in A$, then $x/\pi \in \mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]$ and vice versa, by definition.

Comment: Don't you actually mean $B = \pi(\mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1])$ ? @DarkMalthorp

Comment: Oh yes, I do. My mistake, sorry

Answer (score 0):

$B$ is just the set of rational multiples of $\pi$ (which are contained in $A$). It follows immediately that $B$ is dense in $A$ and has measure zero.